# How to solve gamma from GMM

Tags: probability, distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution

GMM refers to the Gaussian mixture model, cf. [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/gaussian-mixture-models-explained-6986aaf5a95).

Suppose we have $N$ data points (or observations in Statistics) and $K$ Gaussian models to mix. After going through Maximum Likelihood Estimation, we have the formulas for all parameters, i.e. for all $k=1, 2, ..., K,$

> [image]

---

My professor then said, given $z_k,\Sigma_k$ for all $k=1,2,...,K$, one can solve $\gamma_{ik}$ for all $1\leq i \leq N$ and $1\leq k \leq K$.

**My question** is how to solve $\gamma_{ik}$ given $z_k,\Sigma_k$?

I know this shall be a purely linear algebra problem but I have forgot almost all of linear algebra... Any hint is also welcome. I can try with the hint on my own. Thanks!